# Dose-response curve plot in drc package does not show all the points

Tags: r, drc

I am using drc package to plot a dose response curve using 13 points. However, when using the data below, only 6 out of the 13 points are visible in  the plot. Does anyone have a solution to this problem? I suspect the duplicated X values are part of the problem - are replicates being averaged by the model?

```
library(drc)
x<-c(0.001,0.001,0.01,0.01,0.1,0.1,1,1,10,10,0,0,0)
y<-c(15,10,19,11,10,5,13,4,0,0,10,19,21)
model<-drm(y~(x), fct=LL.3())
plot(model)
```

[image: Plot of X vs Y - only 6/13 points visible]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `type="all"` argument:

```
plot(model, type="all")
```

[image]